# Trying to add shimmer/fade effect to an image in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and I am trying to load an image in the background as a watermark and give it a shimmer/fade effect. I was able to get the image to appear but was unable to get it to shimmer.

This is the piece of code where the image appears.

```
.bottomhalf{padding:10px;padding-bottom:4px;background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQxk.png");background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center}
.bottomhalf{filter:brightness(1.05)}
.bottom-field{margin-bottom:12px}
.bottom-descriptor{color:#aaa;font-size:13.4px}
.bottom-value{font-size:18px}
```

If anyone can let know how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try setting different opacity's on your image to achieve the watermark look.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.